# How to Store Levels Data

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im creating a game using SpriteKit but I’m not using sks files fore levels. I don’t to enter in details about the idea of the game before I release it but basically each level is auto generated based on a few numbers. So essentially what defines a level would be these numbers I would like to know where I could store this numbers. If I used sks files I would just have a file per level but in this case should I have them sorted in an array of levels? Should the array be in the level selection viewcontroller ? Should it be in a singleton class? 
Basically what would be a good way to go about storing these values?

Comment: I’m not talking about user data I’m talking about the actual levels.

Comment: If you only need 5 numbers, then just use UserDefaults

Comment: 5 numbers per level. Also it’s the same numbers for all users. I’m not talking about storing gameplay/user data I’m talking about actual level I don’t think it makes much sense to use UserDefaults.

Comment: if it is generated at run time, use the userdefaults.  if it is generated at build time, then just create a plist

Comment: The visual part is generate at runtime (the sknodes) but they are generated based on an algorithm that uses these 5 numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the levels are auto-generated at runtime?

You could use an array of levels, or a file per level. I would just write them to one or more files in your app's documents directory. (I'd probably use one file per level, just to keep it simple and make it so you can easily add more levels without rewriting the whole game layout file each time.)

If you build your level structures out of scalar types, arrays, and dictionaries, (property list objects) then you can write the "object graph" to a property list using the `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` method `write(to:)`.

Alternately you could make your level object conform to the `Codable` protocol, convert it to JSON, and save the JSON data to a file. The `Codable` protocol is easy to use, it's well documented by Apple, and there are tons of tutorials online.

### EDIT

Note that you could also write your data to a property list using the `Codable` protocol. Just like the `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` classes, there are `PropertyListEncoder` and `PropertyListDecoder` classes that will convert your object graph back and forth to property list format. (Binary properties lists are more compact and faster to read and write than JSON.)

Below is a sample playground that defines a custom struct `FooStruct`, makes it Codable, and then uses a `PropertyListEncoder` to write the data to the playground's shared data directory (which you will have to set up if you want to test this code)

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


struct FooStruct: Codable {
    let aString: String
    let anotherString: String
    let anInt: Int
}

let fooArray: [FooStruct] = [FooStruct(aString: "Foo 1",
                                      anotherString: "String 1", anInt: 4),
                             FooStruct(aString: "Foo 2",
                                       anotherString: "String 2", anInt: 7)
]

let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
encoder.outputFormat = .binary

do {
    print(fooArray)
    let data = try encoder.encode(fooArray)
    let plistURL = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("property list.plist")
    try data.write(to: plistURL)
    print("Data written to \(plistURL.path)")
} catch {
    print (error)
}
```

Comment: Yes the levels are generated at runtime. But I don’t think using multiple files is a good ideia each level only need like 5 numbers. It’s nothing complex like procedure generation, running the same 5 numbers multiple times will result in the same level. I think JSON might be a good idea.

Comment: Ok, so save an array of level structs. That's pretty easy. However, you'll be re-writing the file each time you add a new level.

Comment: So I could I use a playground to generate a file add it to app files and then on user side the app only decides file?

Comment: No, I'm just providing some sample Playground code that shows what code to write a custom struct (or array of structs) would look like. You'd modify the above code to read and write your levels data to a file in your app's Documents directory. (Do a search for "URL to iOS Documents directory" to figure out how to get a URL to a file in your app's documents directory.)

Comment: (Although yes, you could certainly pre-generate your levels file on your Mac and ship those pre-written levels files in your app's bundle if you want the levels to be the same for everybody.)

Comment: Yeah the levels should be the same for everyone that’s what I’m trying to achieve. When I said levels are greater at runtime I meant the sknodes. But the actual numbers to feed the building algorithm are the same for everyone.